# Invisible super hidden folders in Windows-7

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I change the setting of folder option in a way that I can see *Hidden* and *Super Hidden* files

[image]

Then I opened *Internet Explorer* (In this case version 9 - But I think there is no different between different versions) and from `Internet Options > General tab > Settings in Browsing history section > view files` opend the below windows : (Internet explorer temporary files in this directory: `C:\Users\TheGoodUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files`) I see the below files only and there is no folder there!

[image]

But when I add `low` or `content.ie5` in the end of that address the below directories opens!
[image]

and

[image]

Finally I did a `dir` command in `CMD`, and I saw the below output :

[image]

Question : What are these directories? Why I can't see them normally?

Answer (score 2):

The folders are normal files. The Temporary Internet Files folder you are viewing in explorer is not the actual folder. It is a Shell Extension added to windows explorer, to Show the folder the way Microsoft want you to see the folder. Another example of a shell extension that doesn't show it's real contents is the Recycle Bin, or the C:\windows\fonts folder.

If you search HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in your windows registry for "Temporary Internet Files" you will see the Class that handles it.. I have two classes in mine, probably because I have updated my Internet Explorer.

You can delete the Class from the registry, so that the Temporary Internet Files folder displays like any other folder, and the Content.IE5 folder etc will all appear...

If you want to change how a folder appears, you would have to create your own shell extension.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for more information.

Comment: **It is a Shell Extension to Show the folder the way M$ want you to see it**. Would you please explain these sentence more? what is M$ stands for?
 and can I hide a specific folder in this way?